# Format string to int

Tags: python, midi

I'm trying to construct a MIDI message.

```
quarter_frame = '0x{}{}'.format(i,x)
clock = [0xF1, quarter_frame]
midiout.send_message(clock)
```

This throws an 'integer required' error.

How can I convert this to an integer?

Comment: What is the full traceback? What type of object is `midiout`? What happens if you use `int(quarter_frame, 16)`? If that works, how are `i` and `x` obtained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> int('1234')
1234
>>> int('0xFF', base=16)
255
```

Comment: No, you don't need to omit `0x`. `int('0xFF', 16)` works, the `0x` prefix is tolerated. Not that it is *required* either, and there are probably better ways of generating the number in this specific case.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sorry I was pretty sure you had some time ago - fixed though.